# MacPorts takes huge time and resources

Tags: macports

I'm installing clang-3.2 and it's taken more than 1.5 hours already running at 400% (all CPU threads at 100%), and 3 GB of hard drive space... Around 20 GB has been written and deleted according to Activity Monitor. What the hell is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably just takes long time to build, it's normal for some ports to take hours to build. If you're curious, you can always locate the logfile using `port logfile clang-3.2` and open it in your favourite text editor or `tail -f $(port logfile clang-3.2)` to see what's going on.

By the way, you do get clang bundled with Xcode, so there is often not any need to build it yourself.

Comment: Unless you need a lower version :\